# Use Python requests to scrape WAN IP from my router

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the WAN IP address from my router (ASUS RT-AC68U) using 'requests' package.

Following online examples I go so far to get username and password.

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
payload = {'login_username': 'xxxxxxxx',
           'login_passwd'  : 'yyyyyyyy'}
data = session.post(url='http://192.168.11.1/Main_Login.asp', data=payload)
print(data, data.text)
```

I do get a huge pile of junk back that appears to tell me that the login failed. At least I don't find the pattern of the WAN IP address as I can see it from the GUI login.

The thing missing seems to be that I somehow need to 'click' on the login button. But I'm not sure how to do that.

[The router login page with html elements opened is here.](http://drgert.dyndns.ws:8000/download/ASUS_RT-AC68U_Login.jpg)

I want to emphasize that this is my own router and I want to do this for no malicious purpose at all. I want to sort-of write my own ddns client.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit in response to t.m.adam.**

The js code looks like this (I'm no js expert):

```
function login(){
var trim = function(val){
val = val+'';
for (var startIndex=0;startIndex<val.length && val.substring(startIndex,startIndex+1) == ' ';startIndex++);
for (var endIndex=val.length-1; endIndex>startIndex && val.substring(endIndex,endIndex+1) == ' ';endIndex--);
return val.substring(startIndex,endIndex+1);
}
```

Thanks,
Gert

**Edit: Abandoned**

I found a way to fix the access to the router via telnet and there is a much easier way to retrieve the IP. (Not sure this would qualify as 'answered')

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: I don't know specifically about ASUS router's case.  But in general, instead of passing those credentials to `Main_Login.asp`, try to pass it to the url of page which you want. If it does not work then try to find if credentials exist into request headers or cookies. Sometimes it is difficult to find it because it is encrypted there. It purely depends on authentication method used to develop web app.

Comment: The Sign In button calls a js function `login()` to post the login data.  Have you checked the js code ?

Comment: The `login()` has no closing bracket, and it only contains a trim function.